# Why android.graphics.Region API does not have any explanation?

Tags: android, region

I have searched various sources for [Region](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Region.html)

For instance I have gone through [this link](https://medium.com/google-developers/a-better-underline-for-android-90ba3a2e4fb#9509). It says Region is a collection of Rectangle as i understood.
But how the all Region.op Works ?

for instance

```
    touchRegion.op(region1 , Region.Op.INTERSECT) // retrune false
    touchRegion.getBounds().intersect(region1.getBounds())  // return true
```

I am totally confused now :-) 
I will welcome some clear and simple explanation. :-)

Comment: Any Update on This ?Team.